# How can I read a URL parameter in App Maker?

Tags: google-app-maker

I want my application to be able to access url parameters, for example I’d like to be able to read “param” if someone navigates to my app using https://script.google.com/myapp?param=20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the google.script.url API from a client script (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/url).

For example:

```js
google.script.url.getLocation(function(location) {
    alert(location.parameter.param);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can URL query string Parameters App Maker as well.

Make sure you are using the published app link ( https://script.google.com/myapp/AppUID/exec?param=20 );

Also google.script.url.getLocation() providing more parametes as below

```
{"parameter":{"param":"20","devConsoleProjectId":"project-id-12345678952362"},"parameters":{"param":["20"],"devConsoleProjectId":["project-id-1234569875625362"]},"hash":""}
```